# Serverless P2P UDP chat

Tags: boost-asio

What is the most simple and straightforward approach for serverless P2P UDP chat in Boost Asio? The chat will work across the internet. There are ready UDP examples but they all maintain client-server approach!

Comment: this question has nothing to do with boost-asio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that by *serverless* you mean a P2P network without a *central control server*.

IMO your question has little to do with boost-asio. asio is a cross-platform network library. You seem to be asking more of a network engineering type question and asio is just one of the tools you can use for implementation.

The examples are client-server in that the example applications possibly fall under the client-server architecture. However the socket code (or asio usage) used to send and receive messages will look the same irrespective of client-server or P2P applications i.e. you send a message to an address and you receive messages on a specified port. The differences will come in at the protocol layer, but this has nothing to do with asio per se.

The following may or may not be of interest to you: there is no *simple* way IMO: users located behind firewalls and NAT means that you need to use techniques such as [STUN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389), [TURN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766) and [ICE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245) to resolve addresses or in the worst case relay data. All these designs require a *server*.